# Ejabberd Clustor file upload not working for one node to second node

Tags: cluster-computing, ejabberd, haproxy

> 2020-08-19 10:57:54.010 [warning]
> <0.1997.0>@mod_http_upload:process:563 Rejecting file
> ca427369-3812-4459-8162-ba4694f831fd.jpg from ::ffff:127.0.0.1 for
> 7049.xxxx.yyyyy.com: Invalid slot

Ejabberd Cluster file sharing not working for one node to second node

The Ejabberd cluster setup via HAProxy load balancer.

In the cluster setup I have `Node1(Ejabberd server 1) and Node2(Ejabberd server 2)`. When I upload file some time get rejected regarding `invalid slot`.

Our setup is HAProxy connect with two nodes(Node1 and Node2)

Note: Single Node(Ejabberd server) working fine.

Please any one share your ideas and feedback.